# Custom Control Code Behind (winRT XAML C++)?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am creating a custom control. The idea is to use 4 sliders to set the RGBA values and a rectangle to display the resulting color. I have created a Dependency Property for the color result so I can bind to it. That is working so far. What I don't understand is how to combine the 4 slider results into a single color value. I know how to do this, just not where to do it. There doesn't seem to be any code behind for custom controls. Where do I implement the logic for my custom controls? What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override OnApplyTemplate method and call GetTemplatePart for each template part control and store these in private fields. Then add dependency properties for each of the RGBA channels and maybe use TemplateBinding to bind slider values to the properties. Finally in the callbacks of your dependency properties set the Color property value.

Comment: OK, this looks like it might get me on the right track. I thought of defining a dependency property for each value, but that seemed a little verbose, I was hoping for something simpler. Oh well, whatever it takes. I'll give it a try tomorrow and mark it as answered if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to use code snippets for dependency properties or if you're into it - T4 templates.

Comment: Are the snippets available in C++? I couldn't find them.